# verificar input vazia

Tags: javascript, mootools

Tenho uma input text e quero verificar se o valor está vazio. No meu exemplo tenho isto:

```
var qttDeclared = tr.getElement("input[name$='[qttDeclared]']").get("value").toInt()
if(qttDeclared == "") {
        console.log("vazio");
    }
```

Mas isto não me está a funcionar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dá-me ideia que estás a usar MooTools... é o caso?

De qq maneira, com essa API podes fazer isso assim:

```
var qttDeclared = tr.getElement("input[name$='[qttDeclared]']").get("value").trim();
if(qttDeclared === "") {
    console.log("vazio");
}
```

Ou seja, o `.get('value')` vai-te dar uma string e o `.trim()` remove os espaços vazios, daí que se estiver vazia vai sobrar só `""`.

Comment: Reparei que há um voto negativo na minha resposta. Um comentário é bem-vindo, não levo a mal se houver coisas a melhorar na resposta.